# three.js texture compression with PNGs

Tags: three.js

Textures with S3TC compression are good e.g. because they allow it to upload the texture faster to the GPU. In this case (working with three.js) I would have to use the DDS format, but textures images in this format even when using the method that compresses best are generally larger than the same PNGs.

Would it be possible to have something that enables one have the best of both worlds?

Comment: Texture compression is about GPU memory usage, not about "faster upload to gpu".

Comment: So it's unpacked on-the-fly in the GPU? Great, even better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what your question is. If you want to download PNGs and upload them to the GPU as DDS you'd have to write a JavaScript DDS compressor (or use emscripten to port a C/C++ compressor). You'd have a some issues though

1. DDS compression is slow.

   Most compressors take on the order of seconds to compress
2. DDS support only exists on desktop

   Most phones don't support DDS

The better question is why do you want to do this? Is your project so AAA with so many resources that you really need to use DDS to squeeze all your textures in memory?

Comment: Good point, encoding something as DDS is indeed slow when dealing with large textures. In my case I now settled with a bit smaller textures, I hope my client is happy, it's about very detailed flat AutoCad data.

PS: I originally categorized it under WebGL because I wondered whether there was maybe some WebGL feature that could be made into a three.js plugin that might have helped me with that. I knew three.js supported DDS.

PPS: I believe on some platforms some texture compression formats are supported (PVRTC?), though haven't checked it out myself yet.